# Why do I get "invalid email address" when I try to add a new user in the "Users and Access" tab of "app store connect"

Tags: ios-appstore, user-account, app-store-connect

I want to add a contractor to our company's App Store Connect account so that I can add him to our TestFlight for our app.

Maybe the problem is because the email address needs to already have an Apple ID.

Comment: This isn't something we can help with. Check the email was typed correctly, otherwise contact Apple support.

Comment: can you send a email with Mail app

Comment: Does it need to be the email address of an existing Apple ID?

Comment: @DougNull No. In the [App Store Connect Help](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-your-team/add-and-edit-users), it is said that: *"Any email address may be used to activate the account, **not necessarily one that’s associated with an Apple ID**. [...] If the account was created with an email address not already associated with an Apple ID, **the user can create an Apple ID during account activation**."*